# Pythagorean triplets in Python

Tags: python

I would like help in solving the following problem:
*Find the product of the triplet of a,b,c for which:
a+b+c = 1000
and a^2+b^2=c^2.*
I have written some python code, but it doesn't output anything. Please could you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
    for a in range(1000):
        for b in range(1000-a):
           c = 1000-a-b
           if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
               print a*b*c
    else:
    break
```

Comment: Is that really your code? Could you review the indentation?

Comment: Also note that `range(1000)` produces the numbers `0,1,2,3,...,999`

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct. You have to fix your formatting and remove this break statement at the end ( this break makes you end the loop on first try. Oh and one more thing. a and b cant be 0 because it would be trivial otherwise (500**2+0**2==500**2).

```
def find_product(sum):
     for a in range(1, sum):
         for b in range(1, sum - a):
             c = sum - a - b
             if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
                   print a*b*c
                   return a*b*c
             else:
                 pass
                 #Keep looking! Dont end here :)
     print 'No such triplet exists!'
```

So the result is:

```
>>> find_product(1000)   # 200**2 + 375**2 = 425**2
31875000
```

Of course your code can be optimized by using some clever mathematical tricks :)